# Can a UIJob defer to a parallel UIJob at regular intervals?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, jobs

I have an eclipse RCP which performs long-running jobs. The job involves graphics processing. While the job is running, a large animated eggtimer is displayed. The graphics job and the animated eggtimer run in separate UIJobs.

During the graphics processing, one method is called which appears to block the animation job. This method contains nested for-loops which analyse the pixels of an image.

I tried adding a `Thread.sleep(0)` inside the for-loop but this had no effect.

What can I add to the for-loop to force it to defer to other jobs at regular intervals?

(I assume that there must be something as this for-loop seems to be the only point in the graphics processing - file access, image creation, image manipulation etc - where the animation job is blocked)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very clear but any long running code must **not** be in the UI thread (UIJob runs in the UI thread).

You must put the long running code in an ordinary Job (or some other background thread). That Job can use `Display.asyncExec` to run UI code in the UI thread.

There isn't any way to 'defer' things in a for loop. Using `Thread.sleep` in the UI thread will block the UI completely.